# How can I put a "Lesson number" in a column field based on time item created

Tags: lookup-column

I have a list being used for a school to record when a student is out of class.

I want to create a column in this list called "Lesson" and have this automatically be filled based on the time that the List Item is created.

So I need to be able to specify when lessons are (eg. 900-940; 940-1020; 1020-1100 etc)

Then I want the user to complete the form and have the "Lesson" field automatically filled with the correct Lesson number.

Any guidance appreciated!
Campbell

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `calculated column` and specify `created` field in the formula.
If you can elaborate more, I can help with the exact formula needed.

One more approach I can suggest for your particular scenario:

1. Create a workflow on item created
2. Extract time from created column of current item
3. Compare the time with your predefined times like : if time is less then 9 then set the Lesson column as "OSH", similarly if it's greater then 9 and less than equal to 9:40 then set Lesson column as Lesson 1.

You can keep lesson column as choice field or as a text column as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Taran - I need the Lesson field to show the following based on the time field:
Created time between 0900-0940 = Lesson 1
Created time between 0940-1020 = Lesson 2
Created time between 1020-1100 = Lesson 3
Created time between 1140-1220 = Lesson 4
Created time between 1220-1310 = Lesson 5
Created time between 1310-1350 = Lesson 6
Created time between 1410-1450 = Lesson 7

Comment: and what about the time when no lesson coincides? Also is lesson1 , lesson 2 would be text field right?
If you need more resuabilty like every lesson is configured with time in another list then we'll need to write a workflow

Comment: If no lesson then instead of a Lesson number, then OSH can show. (Outside school hours).

Comment: is workflow an option?

Comment: Yes Ill explore using a workflow to update a field based on the time the item is created